# How to reinvoke systemd-coredump with an existing coredump file

Tags: systemd, rhel, core-dump

The core_pattern on my system is `|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %e`.
When one of my binaries crashed, the system rebooted before systemd-coredump could complete its processing of the file into a compressed lz4 file.

After reboot, I can see that there is a hidden coredump file created `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` with the name `.#core.mybinaryname.0.8065adab06144e4a96fd0a510d8f60f0.2494.1607347693000000f4cc298460e893db`.

Executing `file` command on the hidden file gave me

```
 ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style
```

How can I let systemd-coredump reprocess this file now that the system has rebooted? My final objective is so that this coredump file shows up when I run `coredumpctl`.